# Jquery Validate Plugin to validate seperate sections with controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have different div sections with some controls in each.
I have a button to navigate from one section to the other. 
all of the divs are in one single form "form1". 
Here is the layout:

form id="form1" 
  div id="section1" 
input type="text" id="1">
input type="text" id="2">
input type="text" id="3">
input type="button">
/div>
div id="section2">
input 4>
input 5>
input 6>
button to next section>
/div>

/form>

I am trying to achieve validating controls in each div when the respective button is clicked.
clicking button in section 1 should validate all controls 1-3 and then navigate to other section.
Let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily accomplish something like this using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //bind click event to section 1's submit button
   $('div#section1').children(':button').click(function() {
      //validate section 1 controls
   });

   //do the same for section 2
   $('div#section2').children(':button').click(function() {
      //validate section 2 controls
   });
});
```

Comment: i am calling the jquery validate plugin. in this case how i call the validate() to all controls in each section

Comment: i did something like this <div id="section1" class="section1"> <control1> <control2> </div>                                          <div id="section2" class="section2"> <controls..................</div> In Jquery I call  $('input[class *="section1"]').each(function() {
  //Validate all methods. This looks simpler

Comment: There a number of ways to implement this and the one I posted is not necessarily the best. Best practice would be to hook the onSubmit event for your forms, then validate controls as required in that form.

Comment: i have only one form and each section is a div not a form.

Comment: Then you only have one onSubmit to hook then :)

Comment: yes. but each time i navigate from one div to the other the current div has to be validated then goto next section. i am struggling to achieve this

Comment: simple hook the event that causes someone to change to a new tab (next button, or tab itself) then validate the current div. If it is valid allow them to move on, otherwise use a preventDefaultBehavior() call to stop it

Comment: i could group them using a class and get the elements of that class and call .each to validate each of them. thnx for the idea

Answer (score 0):

There is official demo at jQuery Validate website:
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/

Comment: The demo is done using seperate forms but i only have one form and each section is a div inside the main form.

Comment: @user695663: No, it is not. There is only one <form> element in the page. Check the source code.